# Обработка двух вебсокетов одновременно

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, websocket, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as multiprocessing
import websocket
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("Отключен")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Подключен")


def a():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("url1",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
def b():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("url2",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=a) 
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=b) 

p1.start() 
p2.start() 

p1.join() 
p2.join()
```

Выводит информацию только с первого вебсокета(url1).

1. Как запустить и обрабатывать два вебсокета одновременно?
2. Как их отключить одновременно?

Comment: А если не `dummy`, а обычный `multiprocessing` подключить? Только проверку на `__main__` поставить и всё как положено, а не так просто.

Comment: В таком случае вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Просто используйте асинхронную библиотеку.